# ¿Es correcto utilizar el document.querySelector() o document.querySelectorAll()?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una consulta relacionada a que en diferentes archivos de extension `php` tengo unos `<div class="MS-content">` y estoy en un archivo `javascript` tratando de seleccionar dicha elemento con esa clase ya que este div contiene a unas "tarjetas" que a su vez cada una tiene un botón para agregar al carro de compras.

```
let allContainerCart = document.querySelector('.MS-content');
```

Con el motivo de que esta clase es la que se repite en todos los archivos y es la clase padre en donde se ubican las tarjetas; **es recomendable la anterior sentencia?** me estoy basando en un video tutorial para aprender sobre esa funcionalidad.

link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2V893ODC2UY&list=PL01E36290C73C6D0F&index=94&t=178s&ab_channel=blackcode

En sí no estoy seguro si solo utilizo el `querySelector()` o `querySelectorAll()` ya que en el video tutorial solo se basa en un archivo.

Comment: Ante la duda, _primero_ debes consultar la documentación acerca de [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) y [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Y como consejo: no estudies netamente en base a videos: busca también otras fuentes de aprendizaje :)

Comment: Es más... ¿Te es útil [Diferencia entre querySelector, querySelectorAll, getElementbyId, getElementbyTag](/q/22538)?

Comment: `querySelector` te devuelve el primer elemento que cumpla con esa condición. `querySelectorAll` te devuelve un arreglo con todos los elementos que la cumplan. Elige depende de lo que necesites.